# how to pass values in textbox by clicking button to a datagridview in another form in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two forms right now, form 1 has a datagridview inside and form 2 has a textbox and a button inside. I want to pass value is entered in textbox to a cell in datagridview in form 2 when I click button. I think code should be written in button_click function in form 1. The basic idea is I don't know how to call datagridview in form 2.

Comment: Let the textbox of Form1 to public, and we can pass the Form1 instance to Form2. And, when you click the form2 button, the text in the form2 can send to the textbox of Form1.

Comment: Atleast show us what you've tried so far..

Comment: I tried to create something like <code>Form1 frm = new Form1();</code>in form 2 but I can't get grid after "frm." before. Now I can get grid with make grid public, but I don't know if there are consequences or not that I do this.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's going to work, but try to define a new property inside your first form class and  inside your button click event get the value from the textbox and save it inside a variable.

So you can get the value of the variable from the previous define property. When you go to the second form  you can update the grid and add the new data to.

If you wanna this passing for multiple values, you can save the all changes on the text box in a list. When you go to the other form you can update your info.

But I don't recommend to make the grid public. Keep it private! I hope it's helpful!

Comment: I really don't know how to do this except making the grid public....For now I can get values in grid in form 2 when I make grid public